# What is the horizontal equivalent of "all of the above"?

Tags: lists, syntactic-analysis, list-order

*All of the above* tends to be used to refer to options that have been described in previous lines in a bulleted list, and I'm wondering how to do the same in a sentence. For example, would the following sentence be correct, and would there be a better way that merely saying "all three":

> They could purchase the Cadillac, the Mercedes, the Hyundai, or all three.

I'm also unsure whether an extra *or* should be used because I'm unsure where the list ends:

> They could purchase the Cadillac, the Mercedes, **or** the Hyundai, or all three.

Comment: The title of this question does not match its body. The consequence of that mismatch is that the accepted answer responds to the body of the question, but not to its title, while the other two answers respond to the title, but not to the rest of it.

Comment: Another alternative is "or all of them."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between each set of commas is one buying option. There is no need for the extra "or" because the reader understands there are 4 options without it:

1. Cadillac
2. Mercedes
3. Hyundai
4. All three

Therefore, your first sentence is correct!

As for your first question, I cannot think of a word to replace "all three." "All three" definitely makes sense and is an efficient way of getting the point across.

Answer (score 5):

*The New Oxford American Dictionary*...
**above**  (adverb) includes

> Mentioned earlier or further up on the same page.

So "All of the above" may be used in horizontal senses as well as vertical.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on your question title more specifically, there is no direct horizontal equivalent.

> All of the above.

This refers to things in a *vertical* location.

> All of the previous options.

This refers to things in a *historical* (temporal) location.

> All of those things to the left.

*Logically*, this would make sense as a reference to things in a *horizontal* location.

However, nobody actually uses it in this way and, therefore, it sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but in respect of what word you can use that doesn't include "above", you can use "aforementioned" or "foregoing".

> aforementioned
>  adj.
>  Mentioned previously.
>  n.
>  The one
>   or ones mentioned previously.
>  [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/aforementioned)
>
> foregoing
>  adj.
>  Said, written, or encountered just before;
>   previous: Refer to the foregoing figures.
>  [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/foregoing)

It is quite formal, but if you want to avoid "above" because it implies a physical direction in space, then you can use them.

Of course in your example you don't need anything of the sort, because the Cadillac, Mercedes and Hyundai are all obvious antecedents, "all three" being the anaphor (referring back to the antecedents). It's probably clearest and simplest the way you just have it.